# django REST API json encoding

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a django application and i made a rest api (webservice) with djangorestframework.
Suppose i have a single table (model). I wrote a serializer for this model and i put a ViewSet class on view.py.
Everything works great: If i browse the API URL with my favorite browser, djangorestframework shows me an human readable page where i can see the content of the table, i can also post a new record. That is great.
When i see the content of the table, i see json encoded data. But when i put a new record, i see this is just a simple HTML post with no json encoding.
I am wondering what is the state of the art in this case: Working with json encoding or not ? What is restfull compliant ?

Next step for me to save data from ajax/javascript client

Should i do something like that:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "/myapi/",
  type : "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: {field1:'value for field1',field2:'....',...}
  success : function(data) { ... }
});
```

Or should i do something like that:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('field1', 'value for field1');
formData.append('field2', '...');
formData.append('userpic', myFileInput.files[0], 'test.jpg');

 $.ajax({
    url : "/myapi/",
    type : "POST",
    data: formData,
    success : function(data) { ... }
  });
```

Thanks

** EDIT **

Here is my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import *
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets
import json    
from rest_framework import viewsets

def index(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html')

class MyModelAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
   serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Here is my model.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    field2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    userpic = models.FileField(blank=True,upload_to='uploads/')

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1','field2','user pic')
```

And here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from algofabapp import views

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api2', views.MyModelViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^api/$', views.MyModelAPIView.as_view()),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your view as well as examples of the data that you're getting?

Comment: Also what you need to do is actually serialise your data into JSON before passing it over to Django. Take a look at [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)